# Regexp for distinguishing uppercase and lowercase not working

Tags: regular-expressions, search

I've made the following command:

```el
(defun search-backward-lowercase-alphabet ()
  (interactive)
  (search-backward-regexp "[a-z]"))
```

But when I run it at the end of a line like the following:

```
abcDEF
```

It just selects the last letter `F`, when I actually want to select the `c`. It doesn't distinguish between uppercase and lowercase at all. How can I fix this?

Comment: `case-fold-search` should be `nil`.

Comment: @abo-abo Thanks! Now it works. It seems it doesn't affect the helm or isearch. Is it only for regexp?

Comment: It's for regexp, but `isearch` and `helm` might bind `case-fold-search` at some points.

Comment: @abo-abo Would it be a bad idea to start my function by setting `case-fold-search` nil and end it with setting it 1, if I ever made sure that it actually affects `isearch` and `helm`?

Comment: @abo-abo I might delete this comment since it's kind of off-topic, but why is that you don't post this as an answer? I could upvote and choose "this solved my question"?

Comment: You can use `"[[:lower:]]"` to match any lowercase character including those with accents etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @abo-abo, you should set `case-fold-search` to nil. However, in order to ensure that it doesn't affect any other part of the system, you can bind in using `let`, as follows:

```
(defun search-backward-lowercase-alphabet ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((case-fold-search nil))
    (search-backward-regexp "[a-z]")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your setting of `case-fold-search`:

> Documentation:
>   Non-nil if searches and matches should ignore case.

This means you need `(setq case-fold-search nil)`.